# Office 365 vs Hosting Exchange at our data center

Tags: exchange, cloud, mx-record

Please give me your view on this question based on your own experiences.

I am trying to determine if I should host our Exchange server in our data center (which host our websites with ~99% uptime).  Currently it is hosted at our dev office, in a 2003 domain environment. The problem here is that there are power outages like once a month and it isn't reliable enough.

If we will host ourselves, we are thinking of installing a secondary 2008 DC along with Exchange, with a tunnel to the office. We want to avoid a case where the power will go out on the primary DC and bring down the Exchange service at the data center. Is that possible?

If we choose Office 365, will we need to change the MX record for the entire domain? If so, we'll have about 80 different Outlooks to reconfigure and somehow import the mail into Office 365, correct?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Exchange are you running?

Comment: Exchange 2007 in Win 2k3 domain

Answer (score 2):

First to clear up some factual problems with your post:

- There is no such thing as primary/secondary domain controllers any more. All DC's are equal partners (more-or-less). The differences are beyond the scope of this question.
- Changing the MX record has nothing to do with Outlook configuration.

---

Hosting your Exchange server offsite in a data center is acceptable. If you decide to go this route, make sure that your DC is it's own server (physical or virtual). DO NOT install Exchange on a DC.

Depending on the size of your existing Exchange deployment, migration to Office 365 is pretty easy. Once you sign up for an account, you configure a connection to Office 365 so it can access your Active Directory domain and Exchange deployment. Then you import users and schedule mailbox migrations. It's fairly automatic.

You will need to change your MX records to Office 365 if you want it to survive power outages.

If you are running Outlook 2007 or newer, you should not need to reconfigure any of your clients. After a user's mailbox is moved, Autodiscover will automatically change the settings.

---

As an alternative to any of the above, you might look at something like AppRiver or MX Logic. You point your MX to their servers and they receive all of your mail for you, perform SPAM and virus filtering, and deliver it to your servers. In the event of a server failure on your end, they just hold on to your mail until you recover.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, we currently use MXLogic. What I meant by changing MX records is if I'll have to point them to Office365, which you say I will. If I do so, how does the Office365 Exchange sync with our AD, or does it at all? If so, wouldn't it be affected by a power outage?

Comment: Office 365 effectively runs a limited DC with your data in their environment to support Exchange.